# a good mobile add platform for android app

Tags: android

I am looking integrate my android apps with some ads.

I tried different add platform

- airpush - This gives developers a good revenue but the app starts lagging once integrated because their api is not doing all the network requests in a seperate thread.
- Admob - This is good but the revenue I can earn is comparatively low because we get paid only when users click the ads.
- Leadboult - So far it appears that this is the best one to go but because of the Google's new policy on advertisements the revenue developers can earn is going very low.

So can anyone comment out your experiences in different add platforms and which one is the best one to give a try?

Comment: Guess what "android ads sdk" provides in a Google search? :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick Google on this should provide APIs as: [admob](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download), [pubmatic](http://www.pubmatic.com/pub_mob_sdk.php) or [OpenXAddSDK](http://www.openx.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Please try admob provided by google